# How to compile a program of the C language manually on MS-DOS instead of Borland

Tags: c, turbo-c

I need to compile a program in MS-DOS. I have the Borland editor, and I can compile the program using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>, but what does it do at the backend? I want to compile it in MS-DOS. I’m trying this:

```
cd c:\tc\bin
tcc -o hello.exe hello.c
```

where `hello.c` is my file, and `hello.exe` the file I want to produce. It's not working. What should I do? And how do I compile a `.cpp` file manually from MS-DOS?

Comment: "Its not working" What does that mean? can you show us the error?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy This is the error I get, hello.exe the file not found and probably he might be facing the same !

Comment: You could possibly also be helped by this page: http://www.sandroid.org/TurboC/functionlist.html

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant he wants the tcc command line options ! not the Turbo that uses gcc commands instead!

Comment: Is the question about [Tiny C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) (TCC) or about [Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) (allegedly compiler executable name `TCC` or `tcc`)?

Comment: How can the two be distinguished? By the folder name "`c:\tc\bin`"? [The tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcc) is for "TCC" / "Tiny C Compiler", but the tag wiki is empty.

Comment: There is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55943295/2193968   If that isn't what you are after you could leave the -o test.exe out and then rename the executable once it is created.

Comment: Note that the OP [has left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *Last seen more than 7 years ago*. But it ought to be possible to untangle the intent, incl. [which compiler it is actually about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343287/how-to-compile-a-program-of-the-c-language-manually-on-ms-dos-instead-of-borland/32967806#comment134581241_7343287).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these things must work:

```
c:\tc\bin\tcc -c File.c     \\ To generate the object file
c:\tc\bin\tcc -o File.obj   \\ To generate the EXE file from the object file. And please use .obj, not .o
c:\tc\bin\ tcc -run File.c  \\ To generate the EXE file without the .obj file
c:\tc\bin\File.exe          \\ To run the EXE file
```

I don’t know why the

```
tcc -o good.exe File.obj \\ Not working. The error is 'good.exe' file not found
```

I don't think we can give a name to the *.exe* file on the `tcc` command line prompt, but it's possible in GCC. I don’t know about TCC much. If I find it, I will let you know it!

Just take a look at these *[Tiny C Compiler Reference Documentation](https://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html)*. This is what I found on Google. And googling makes you more powerful, so keep on googling the things when you don’t know.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry.  user672560 asked about Borlands Turbo C compiler for DOS from ca 1990, or so.  You gave a link to Fabrice Bellards TCC. While the executable names unfortunately are the same, the compilers are very much not.

Comment: Thnx Niko Its Work Yahoooo ;)

Comment: "`c:\tc\bin\ tcc`" doesn't seem right (with the space).

Comment: Re *"I don't think we can give a name to the .exe file on the tcc command line prompt,"*: [It might be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343287/how-to-compile-a-program-of-the-c-language-manually-on-ms-dos-instead-of-borland/7359784#7359784) with the "`-e`" command-line parameter: "`-exxx   Executable file name`"

Comment: The reference is to [Tiny C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) (TCC). This has *** *** *** *** *** ***nothing*** *** *** *** *** ***  to do with Turbo C++ (the name of the Turbo C++ compiler executable happens to be `TCC` or `tcc`). Unless the question is actually about Tiny C Compiler (the question is very vague and unclear).

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, Borland/Turbo C compiler's command line options didn't look like gcc options. You should try `tcc /?` for a command line help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Turbo C++ Version 3.00 Copyright (c) 1992 Borland International
Syntax is: TCC [ options ] file[s]     * = default; -x- = turn switch x off
 -1      80186/286 Instructions    -2      80286 Protected Mode Inst.
 -Ax     Disable extensions        -B      Compile via assembly
 -C      Allow nested comments     -Dxxx   Define macro
 -Exxx   Alternate Assembler name  -G      Generate for speed
 -Ixxx   Include files directory   -K      Default char is unsigned
 -Lxxx   Libraries directory       -M      Generate link map
 -N      Check stack overflow      -O      Optimize jumps
 -P      Force C++ compile         -Qxxx   Memory usage control
 -S      Produce assembly output   -Txxx   Set assembler option
 -Uxxx   Undefine macro            -Vx     Virtual table control
 -X      Suppress autodep. output  -Yx     Overlay control
 -Z      Suppress register reloads -a      Generate word alignment
 -b    * Treat enums as integers   -c      Compile only
 -d      Merge duplicate strings   -exxx   Executable file name
 -fxx    Floating point options    -gN     Stop after N warnings
 -iN     Max. identifier length    -jN     Stop after N errors
 -k      Standard stack frame      -lx     Set linker option
 -mx     Set Memory Model          -nxxx   Output file directory
 -oxxx   Object file name          -p      Pascal calls
 -r    * Register variables        -u    * Underscores on externs
 -v      Source level debugging    -wxxx   Warning control
 -y      Produce line number info  -zxxx   Set segment names
```

So, I think you should type:

`tcc hello.c` for C programs and `tcc -P hello.cpp` for C++ programs.

Comment: What produced the output? `tcc` without any command-line parameters?

Comment: Though [it isn't clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343287/how-to-compile-a-program-of-the-c-language-manually-on-ms-dos-instead-of-borland/32967806#comment134581241_7343287) if the question is about Tiny C Compiler (TCC) or about Turbo C++ (allegedly compiler executable name `TCC` or `tcc`).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think we can infer from "Borland" that it's not about Bellards TCC. Pretty hard core necromancing of a question about MSDOS programming, now one more decade obsolete! :-D  Let's see if someone leaves a new answer ten years from now.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Prof Falken's answer

`tcc file.c` <-- will compile in C

`tcc file.cpp` <-- will compile in cpp

tcc file.ext  where .ext is anything other than cpp, will compile in C  Unless --P is used then cpp is used to compile it, in which case .cpp is used, even if the extension is .c

I am running TCC in a VM and can't copy/paste from there here. But your test should find the same result as mine, if not, then perhaps I erred, but you can test for yourself given this code that works in C and not CPP, and code that works in CPP and not C. You can then experiment with changing the extension, and using -P or not.

**The following code works in C only**

`conly.c`

(A C++ expert told me re the following example, works in C and not C++,  because C allows void* -> T* conversions. C++ does not)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main() {int *x=malloc(4);}
```

**The following code works in C++ only**

`cpponly.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
 int a=9;
 int& b=a;
 printf("b=%d",b);
}
```