# Maximum length of identifiers in Turbo C++ and Dev-C++ for both C and C++ languages

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, standards, identifier

What is the maximum length of variable identifiers of C and C++ in [Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) and [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B)?

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Comment: hi sana!.I am not the one who downvoted you but Please always show some effort before asking the questions here.Otherwise you will be downvoted and might be your question deleted.Please do read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I have researched all other tools like MS visual studio takes 1028 characters for identifier. This is the maximum length of variable name, cannot exceed it. What is length restriction of identifiers in turbo and dev tools ?

Comment: o larki what are you trying to say? what do you mean by `This is the maximum length of variable name, cannot exceed it. What is length restriction of identifiers in turbo and dev tools`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352209/max-identifier-length read this page and answer me specifically of the same question for Turbo and Dev.

Comment: `iN `, is the swith you can use on TCC to get the max identifier length. [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343287/how-to-compile-a-program-of-c-language-manually-on-ms-dos-instead-of-borland)

Comment: It is not clear whether you mean the completely obsolete ancient dinosaur Borland Turbo C++ for DOS, or the semi-outdated Turbo C++ from 2008. Which of these archaeological items are you referring to? The answer will be quite different.

Comment: @Lundin "archaeological items" . thats nice :-)

Comment: @Koushik Shetty: TCC is ambigious. The ***primary*** meaning of [TCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) is [Tiny C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler). Turbo C++ is normally spelled out.

Comment: @Koushik Shetty: Or is `tcc` the name of the executable (for the compiler)?

Comment: OK, the name of the executable for the Turbo C++ compiler [is `tcc` or `TCC`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343287/how-to-compile-a-program-of-the-c-language-manually-on-ms-dos-instead-of-borland/7359784#7359784).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) uses the [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) port of GCC (`g++` for C++), hence it has an *unlimited* identifier length.

[Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B): use the `iN` switch on `tcc` to get the maximum identifier length.

Comment: A reference: Command-line parameter [`iN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343287/how-to-compile-a-program-of-the-c-language-manually-on-ms-dos-instead-of-borland/7359784#7359784): *"Max. identifier length"*

Answer (score 4):

If you mean variable length, then it differs from compiler to compiler:

- [Microsoft C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B): 2048 characters
- [Intel C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler): 2048 characters
- [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (executable `g++`): No limit

But keep in mind that Annex B of the C++ Standard says that an implementation should support identifiers at least 1024 characters long, but this is not mandatory.

Dev-C++ uses the [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) or TDM-GCC 64-bit port of GCC as its compiler. Dev-C++ can also be used in combination with [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) or any other GCC-based compiler. 
AND
Turbo C++ was itself a C++ compiler and integrated development environment and computer language originally from Borland, but *most* recently it was distributed by [Embarcadero Technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Technologies), which acquired all of [Borland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland)'s compiler tools with the purchase of its [CodeGear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeGear) division in 2008 (ref: Wikipedia)
Please [see this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392726/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-identifier-names-in-c).

Comment: Are these compilers of Turbo and Dev ?

Comment: Dev-C++ uses MinGW distro of GCC, and Turbo is so old no one cares about its limits.

Comment: But I care, I want to know exactly in Turbo and Dev for which you guys have devoted me. :(

Comment: ok hold on.See the edit in which i referenced a question

Comment: We aren't very devoted to you, no.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard, section 5.2.4.1 says:

1) 63 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or a macro name (each universal character name or extended source character is considered a single character)

2) 31 significant initial characters in an external identifier (each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 0000FFFF or less is considered 6 characters, each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 00010000 or more is considered 10 characters, and each extended source character is considered the same number of characters as the corresponding universal character name, if any)

Also have a look at http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.2.4.1.html, but this just what standard says, as @freak mentioned it can also vary from compiler to compiler

Comment: Wait, @Zoidberg, did you miss the fact that this answer talkes about [tag:C], not [tag:C++] ?

Comment: And this is why C is not attractive to Java programmers.

Comment: it need not be attractive. its the power it holds that make it so loved by billion others..

Comment: @Zoidberg, what do you mean? Because there is documented standards or because there are people who read them?

Comment: Because C has such a short standard limit on the lengths of identifiers.

Comment: @Zoidberg People who write identifiers longer than 63 characters _deserve_ bugs. For the record, C99 increased the minimum number of characters, I believe it was 30-something before. But any implementation is free to use as many characters as they like, the standard only states an absolute minimum.

Comment: @Lundin Ah, so that is why frameworks like Spring have so many bugs!